# socket.emit back for sending data to same client who sent it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my program I am trying to make the client send data over to the server and after this the data that was sent to the server is sent back to the client who sent the request originally. The only problem I am having is that once the data is sent over to the server it does not seem to want to be sent back to the client who sent it.

client side HTML

```
 <form id="name_form">
      <div class="row">
           Name:
           <input id="name_input" type = "text" required maxlength="40">
           <button class="btn btn-info" id="submit_button">submit <i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:48px;"></i></button>
            </div>
 </form>
```

client side JS:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name_input").value;
socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080"); 
socket.emit("new-user", name); 

socket.on("welcome", function(data) 
{ 
console.log("recived welcome"); 
});
```

Server side

```
var name_list = ["bob", "sam", "jim"]
io.on("connection", function(socket) 
{
    socket.on("new-user", function(data)
    { 
    socket.emit('welcome', name_list); 
    });
});
```

When I look at the console on the client side in my web browser, the message `"received welcome"` does not come up. With the `socket.emit()` on the server side, this makes me think that the data that the client sent over to the server will be sent directly back over to the client that sent it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218254/discussion-on-question-by-digitalrookie4-socket-emit-back-for-sending-data-to-sa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the form in your HTML. Everytime the form is submitted the page gets reloaded(that's the default behaviour of a form). When the page gets reloaded the socket which was listening to event "welcome" gets resetted and is no longer listening so you aren't getting any broadcast event.

The following is one of the way to prevent this default behaviour

- Add a **action="javascript:void(0);"** in form tag

  ```
  <form id="name_form" action="javascript:void(0);">
  ```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKS NOW. YOU ARE AN ABSOLUTE LEGEND! :)